# Making dynamic layer using QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I have a earthquake dataset that is regulary updated. I want to extract those earthquakes that falls within a given geographical area. No problem, I'll do an intersection. Then I get a temporary layer that will be lost the next time I open QGIS.

Is it somehow possible to make a "dynamic layer" that will be recalculated next time I open QGIS i.e. with what is then the current content of the layers used for the intersection?

Something like having a model that is run automatically and updates the resulting layer rather than adding a new.

Comment: Are you looking for virtual layers? See: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html?#creating-virtual-layers

Comment: It's possible to only show features within areas with expression `overlay_within`.

Comment: Does this help : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/394293/looking-for-a-way-to-create-dynamically-updating-point-layers-in-qgis-linked-to

Answer (score 3):

There are a variety of features QGIS has that may help. This answer is not a cookbook recipe, since it depends on exactly what you want to do (and why) and some of the syntax is provider-specific (how you're accessing the underlying main layer). It is more a menu of things for you to explore.

1. You can load a layer with a **provider filter** to constrain which features are loaded. This can be accessed via `Layer properties / Source / Query builder`. You'll want to read the manual at https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#query-builder since the syntax and functionality depends on the data provider being used to access the data.
2. You can load a **virtual layer** based on the main layer using SQL syntax. This can be accessed at `Layer / Add Layer / Add/Edit Virtual Layer` and docs are at https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html?#creating-virtual-layers
3. If your context is that you need to calculate additional info/fields for features in your ROI, and just don't want to have to process (and update) every time the main layer updates, then you could just load the main layer, and add **virtual fields** using the Field Calculator. (Make sure you check the box `Create virtual field`) These are then dynamically calculated, and QGIS is pretty good at calculating them only when needed, so you won't have the overhead hit of them being (re)calculated for features outside your ROI.